# How to determine if a Java Class implements a particular Interface

Tags: java, class, reflection

I'm trying to use reflection to determine whether a passed-in class implements an `IsWdidget` interface:

```
public boolean isAWidget(Class<?> clzz) {
    Class<?> runtimeClass = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(clzz.getName());
    Class<?>[] impls = runtimeClass.getInterfaces();
    for(Class<?> clz : impls)
        if(clz.getName().equals(IsWidget.class.getName()))
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Is this the best/most effecient way of determining this? I also see a `IsWidget.class.isAssignableFrom(Class<?>)` method...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would use the [`isAssignableFrom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)) method to determine if `IsWidget` is a superinterface:

```
return IsWidget.class.isAssignableFrom(clzz);
```

To quote from the linked Javadoc above:

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object
>   is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the
>   class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter.

Answer (score 1):

1) this makes no sense

```
  Class<?> runtimeClass = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(clzz.getName());
```

try this with any class

```
    Class<?> runtimeClass = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(clzz.getName());
    System.out.println(runtimeClass == clzz);
```

you will get

```
true
```

so if you remove this line and work directly with clzz it's already more efficient

2) try this

```
class X extends Thread {
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(X.class.getInterfaces()));
}
```

you will get

```
[]
```

this is similar to what your func is doing, but in fact X implements Runnable

3) and this is really efficient one-line solution to check if a class implements an interface

```
    System.out.print(Runnable.class.isAssignableFrom(X.class));
```

output

```
true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getInterfaces()` method if you are having a `Class` object.

```
    Class c[] = clzz.getInterfaces();   
    if(Arrays.asList(c).contains(IsWidget.class))
    {
        return true;
    }
```

The getInterfaces method gives you an array of `Class` representing the `interfaces`. Or you could also use isAssignableFrom method as follows:

```
IsWidget.class.isAssignableFrom(clzz);
```

If you have an `Object` you can use the `instanceof` method.

Comment: This will determine if `clzz` is a superclass of `IsWidget`; it's backwards.

Comment: @rgettman: Corrected. Thanks for notifying.:)

Answer (score 0):

If that works, it should be fine. You could also try calling the `cast` method of the `Class` class and do a try and catch.

Comment: This does work, but it really abuses the point of using a try/catch block. Plus the thrown exception will make the call more expensive than it has to be (though I'm not sure how much more efficient it would be to use reflection to determine the implementing interface)